# How to identify programically in QML app, where is located my sqlite database file

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, sqlite

I have QML application which use as well C++ .
From C++ I need to connect to DB ( sqlite ) . For this I need to know the exact name and location of the database file . How to identify it ?
Or how to connect from C++ to SQLite without this exact location ?

Meanwhile I searched and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602768/file-storage-location-for-ubuntu-application). So I suggest this way to identify it :

```
$HOME/.local/share/myapplicationname/Database/filewithextension.sqlite
```

The database was created from the application from javascript using this command :
db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("OwnDict.db", "", "App NAme", 100000);

Comment: The exact name and location of what database file?  If you created it, you should know where it is.  If you didn't, you'll need to tell us who created it for us to have any hope of helping you.

Comment: The database was created from the application using javascript command : db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("OwnDict.db", "", "App NAme", 100000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases created from QML LocalStorage are saved in `~/.local/share/<appid>/Databases/`, where *<appid>* is the `applicationName` in your `MainView`.  The databases have hexadecimal names and the extension *.sqlite*.  Each has an associated *.ini* file with the name and description from the first and third arguments to `openDatabaseSync`.

If you only create one database via LocalStorage, there will of course be only one database in this directory.  If you create more, you may have to parse the *.ini* files to find the right one.  However, in my limited testing, the database files seem to get deterministic file names, so you may be able to figure out the filename on your device and then hardcode that value into your C++ code.